# Server name contains port

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

One of our clusters returns the port number as part of the Server Name. See example below

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY ('ServerName')

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ClusterName\InstanceName,1433

(1 row affected)
```

The InstanceName Server Property returns as expected only the Instance Name. I can't figure out why the Port Number was added.

So far it does not cause major issues. But I would like to remove the port name so we don't run into potential issues with scripting in the future since this is the only server that exhibits this behavior.

Comment: Not sure where in Configuration Manager you want me to look, but I can't see anything that contains the Port (except for the port configuration of course). I also exported the SQL server Registry from a good server and this odd ball and nothing popped out. `sys.servers` does contain the port number in the `name` and `data_source` columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Configuration Manager lists all the instances installed on the machine:

> [image]

If it says `InstanceName,1433` there, I'm not sure exactly how it got that way, because installation shouldn't have let whoever installed SQL Server to proceed with `,1433` as part of the instance name. If this is the case, no, you cannot give the instance a new name; you rename an instance by installing a new instance (from [the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/rename-a-computer-that-hosts-a-stand-alone-instance-of-sql-server)):

> The following steps cannot be used to rename an instance of SQL Server. They can be used only to rename the part of the instance name that corresponds to the computer name.

If Configuration Manager looks right and only `sys.servers` and `@@SERVERNAME` look wrong, perhaps you got in this state because someone ran:

```
EXEC sys.sp_dropserver N'ClusterName\InstanceName';
GO
EXEC sys.sp_addserver N'ClusterName\InstanceName,1433', N'LOCAL';
GO
```

I'm not willing to try that but you can certainly try to get out of your jam by running the reverse:

```
EXEC sys.sp_dropserver N'ClusterName\InstanceName,1433';
GO
EXEC sys.sp_addserver N'ClusterName\InstanceName', N'LOCAL';
GO
```

...then consider reducing the permissions of anyone who shouldn't be messing around with the server like that.

Comment: I can confirm that *some* items initialize their data from sys.servers, no need to break your instance.